# Exchanging AccessToken, returns error "invalid_grant" code 9002313

Tags: oauth-2.0, outlook, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to get access token of a user from an Outlook Add-in, then exchange it for a graph api token, but I get this error:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid.\r\nTrace ID: 4e9c3fab-96b3-4d26-a947-969da5ada400\r\nCorrelation ID: 7bdd112e-5afd-4468-bdac-0586e8dfe2b4\r\nTimestamp: 2022-05-09 10:18:27Z",
    "error_codes": [
        9002313
    ],
    "timestamp": "2022-05-09 10:18:27Z",
    "trace_id": "4e9c3fab-96b3-4d26-a947-969da5ada400",
    "correlation_id": "7bdd112e-5afd-4468-bdac-0586e8dfe2b4",
    "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=9002313"
}
```

This is how I make the call:

[image: Postman data]

This is how I get the access Token:

```
    OfficeRuntime.auth
      .getAccessToken({ allowConsentPrompt: true, allowSignInPrompt: true, forMSGraphAccess: true })
      .then((res) => { ...
```

And these are my permissions:
[image: permissions]

Comment: Did you try to use the `office-addin-sso` package to register the add-in in Azure? Does it work in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same error in my environment. I have registered an Azure AD application and granted the same permissions as below:***

[image]

I have included below parameters in **Postman** and got the access token successfully.

[image]

***To reproduce the same error, I replaced the value of **`code`** with some token value and got result like below:***

[image]

So, the reason behind getting that error is giving **wrong value** to **`code`** parameter.

To get the correct **`code`** value, try to form an **authorize URL** like below:

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/your_tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=your_client_id&response_type=code&redirect_uri=your_redirect_uri&response_mode=query&scope=user.read openid profile offline_access email mail.read files.read.all
&state=12345](https://login.microsoftonline.com/066cb846-7de7-44e2-99b8-93ad2b99a60d/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?%20client_id=ee47a8ba-a7a6-4bdf-b4a4-7272946ae201%20&response_type=code%20&redirect_uri=http://localhost%20&response_mode=query%20&scope=user.read%20openid%20profile%20offline_access%20email%20mail.read%20files.read.all%20&state=12345)

Open the above URL in browser, select your account and accept the permissions consent. You can find **`code`** value in address bar like below.

[image]

***Copy that value and replace the previous **`code`** parameter value with this, you will get access token successfully.***